# How to use 3 tier architecture using WPF forms?

Tags: wpf

I am just starting with a new project. I have some forms which stores data and some reports. I have decided to use WPF for the purpose. I am new to WPF, so needs help. I need some sample application of WPF which stores the data in database using 3 tier architecture.

I need guidance on following points:

1. How to use 3 tier architecture 
   using WPF?
2. Do i need to use WCF alongwith WPF? Advantages and disadvantages??

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do something like 3-tier architecture in WPF is called [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), you should check that out.

You don't need to use WCF with WPF. I think that unless the benefits of having application tier on a different computer are significant, you should keep it on the same computer and use it as a library directly from your presentation code.

Comment: Thanks. Can I have a simple 3 tier architecture like : UI layer, Business layer (Class Library) , Database Layer(Class Library)?? I would prefer this if it is possible as I am more used to it now..

Comment: @GirishK: Model -> DB/Business, View -> UI, ViewModel -> Business/UI. It's not as much of a line in the sand, but you can usually utilize a BAL/DAL in your Model/ViewModels easily.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that you are talking about enterprise application architecture which contains 3 tiers (UI, BL, DB)

And WPF is a UI (frontend) technology.

So if you want to make some nice application, for UI you can choose WPF, for server communication(if you need it) use WCF services and DA layer should be at server side.

Possibly if your application is highly dependend on server, you can choose silverlight, or event ASP.NET application(there are many nice report controls).

Comment: I have a simple app with 5 - 6 small forms and 2 reports which will most probably be installed on 2 machines. Do I need to use WCF?? Is it ok if i simply go with .net style  3 tier architecture with no services??

Comment: You mean that your 2 installed applications dont need external server(except for DB) and dont communicate with each other ? In that case - No, you dont need WCF

Comment: I think, you are getting it right. But to be  more clear, I will have 2 different users of 2 different roles (administrator, reception) will use my system. Roles can be added. So I will have 1 central database accessed by multiple machines in LAN. Can i satisfy all these requirements without using WCF services??

Comment: Look, in the architecture with WCF, you can create an independet server layer and update it rather seamless for users. Also SQL connection is rather secure(only WCF server needs one), and nobody will have even posibility to play(or something worse) with databse. On the other side WCF service can be rather complicated, and if security and client updates are no so important, it can be useless